# Is it possible to execute net_enable_timestamp() from user space in linux?

Tags: linux, network-programming, linux-kernel

I'd like to enable timestamping received network packets. I found that function net_enable_timestamp() should do this form me, but I can't find it neither in CentOS nor in ArchLinux. But when I execute:

```
# cat /proc/kallsyms | grep net_enable_timestamp
c126a330 T net_enable_timestamp
```

In kernel source from kernel.org it's located in linux/netdevice.h, but not in both distros mentioned above. Is it possible to execute it? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with enabling SO_TIMESTAMP on the socket and accessing the timestamp of the last message via ancilliary data?

Alternatively you can call ioctl(socket, SIOCGSTAMP) as described in socket(7)

---

Edit: Looking at the kernel source code, it appears that net_enable_timestamp() actually gets called indirectly when you do setsockopt(sock, SO_TIMESTAMP ...

So my answer answers your question :)

Comment: yes! you are right! I don't know why I ommited .c files while digging through kernel source and trying to solve my problem.